# To print data from database using join query

Tags: php, mysql, join

Newbie to join queries. I have written a join query for two tables viz; Candidate and candidate_contact. 
Where cand_number is primary key in candidate table and FK in candidate_contact. also cand_cid is my Primary key in candidate_contact
 But after submitting the query the data is not being displayed. 
Its only printing till the -echo " in result ";

```
if(isset($_POST['candi_s_by_code']))
{
  $sql="SELECT * FROM candidate,candidate_contact WHERE candidate.cand_number=candidate_contact.cand_number AND candidate.cand_number=$candname";   
  echo "selected candidate code";
} 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
echo "in result";

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
  $FirstName  =$row['cand_fname']; 
  $LastName=$row['cand_lname']; 
  $Mail=$row['cand_mail'];
  $Telephone=$row['cand_tel']; 
  $Mobile=$row['cand_mobile'];
}
```

Comment: try to check if data is coming using `print_r($result);`

Comment: @MujahedAKAS..ust a moment i will try it.

Comment: @MujahedAKAS its not working. its going in infinite loop.

Comment: Don't use php's deprecated mysql_ API. See mysqli_/PDO and prepared statements. Don't use implicit/comma join syntax. Use explicit JOIN SYNTAX. Finally, it seems unlikely that cand_number could be equal to $candname

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you. But this is my try code. If this works .. i am using mysqli . Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are closing button's click bracket over the sql query so do it like this i dont no from where u r getting  `$candname` by the way

```
if(isset($_POST['candi_s_by_code']))
{
  $sql="SELECT * FROM `candidate,candidate_contact` WHERE `candidate.cand_number`=`candidate_contact.cand_number` AND `candidate.cand_number`='".$candname."'";   


$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 


while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 
  $FirstName  =$row['cand_fname']; 
  $LastName=$row['cand_lname']; 
  $Mail=$row['cand_mail'];
  $Telephone=$row['cand_tel']; 
  $Mobile=$row['cand_mobile'];
}}
```

Comment: I Just tried But it is giving error : Unknown column 'candidate.cand_number' in 'where clause'

Comment: @vinod so the problem may be in ur query check your database table's column name

Comment: thnks for Your help, we have checked database and query too.but still its not working. it is giving same result.

Comment: so can u post ur db structure

Comment: @Vicky...thank you Vicky..from all above conversations we did combined codes and it worked. Some of your code and some of above. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the varaible `$candname` in your query is correct. My best guest from you code is, you proberbly were supose to use `$_POST['candi_s_by_code']` instead of `$candname`
try this

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `candidate,candidate_contact` WHERE `candidate.cand_number`=`candidate_contact.cand_number` AND `candidate.cand_number`='".$_POST['candi_s_by_code']."'";
```

Comment: try to echo the value of $candname, and why are you equating $candname with cand_number ???

Comment: @eddysoft.....Basically its a search query. where user will enter code.and it will compare and  search that code in database. 
cand_number is database column and $candname is textbox field ID.

Comment: @eddysoft...i implemented your code but it is giving error as: Unknown column 'candidate.cand_number' in 'where clause'

Comment: @eddySoft..Thank you eddy for the tech advices. We have used some of your code and some of others and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if you have

`$_POST['candi_s_by_code']` by using `echo $_POST['candi_s_by_code'];`

and
`$candname` by using `echo $candname;`

before select query. and change your select query as follows

`select * from candidate join candidate_contact  ON candidate.cand_number =candidate_contact.cand_number where candidate.cand_number='$candname';`

if you dont want to change your select query try to add single quotatoion **'$candname'** around your php variable in select query.

Comment: we have tried above code, but its not giving output. without errors.

Comment: @MujahedAKAS..Thank you AKAS..Some changes to your code and it worked for me..Thank you. I will post the correct query.